Video seems Jittery when i use a image strip
When i import a image sequence strip in video editing the animation is very jittery and bouncy, same thing happens when rendered.
I have an example video right here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NbusUyhlhb3KkQHtEHGI6SZnsLPvRmdE/view?usp=sharing
The Cube is supposed to rise up, rotate, and scale up at the same time in linear easing.
Edit: Im using Blender 3.6.4

Well, that's not how it's supposed to be I guess... have never experienced something like that before, but since it should not look like this it is either a bug which we cannot do anything about here and you should rather report it or, we would need your blend file to check the settings and also the image sequence to check why this happens. Just seeing the result does not give us any information where the issue might be located.

are u sure that you imported your images in the right order? it would be much better to provide a blend file than just a video, so we can be sure what's going on.

Hello, Blundus.. @Chris might be on to this one.. Sequence import does not automatically order the files alphanumerically.. it depends on the sort-order in the file explorer.. can you check that out first, and report back? If not the problem, please share as suggested on https://blend-exchange.com/

@RobinBetts Thats really weird because every one is number in the 0001 format

Since you did not provide any source material or any information how you imported your image sequence (maybe the images are named incorrectly so that they are sorted wrong after import?), so I can only tell in which order they should have been give the animation you describe in the question.
The mp4 has 30 frames, to make the (video) frames 1 to 30 show the correct motion the order has to be:
2-1-4-3-6-5-8-7-10-9-13-12-11-15-14-18-17-16-20-19-23-22-21-25-24-28-27-26-30-29
So you have at first a few pairs of two in reverse order, then sometimes inbetween triplets in reverse order.
